# Fire Menu Strip Item Click Event Dynamically in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, event-handling, mouseclick-event, menustrip

I have already added a menu strip controller and added click events for those menu items.

Ex:

```
private void mnuaddTestingBuyersForFigures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmAddTestingBuyersForFigure obj = new frmAddTestingBuyersForFigure();
   objUserManagerBll.SetAccess(obj, User.UserID);
   IsAlreadyLoded(obj);
}

private void mnuOperatorIncentive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmOperatorIncentive obj = new frmOperatorIncentive();
   objUserManagerBll.SetAccess(obj, User.UserID);
   IsAlreadyLoded(obj);
}

private void mnuSetUpIncentiveMonthProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmSetUpWeeksForIncentiveMonth obj = new frmSetUpWeeksForIncentiveMonth();
   objUserManagerBll.SetAccess(obj, User.UserID);
   IsAlreadyLoded(obj);
}
```

Here I want fire above click event from another event. I just want to pass the menu strip name as parameter to the method and fire corresponding event of it.

Ex :

```
ShowMe("mnuSetUpIncentiveMonthProcess");
//Out put open the frmSetUpWeeksForIncentiveMonth form

ShowMe("mnuOperatorIncentive");
//Out put open the frmOperatorIncentive form
```

**Without using conditional statements**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the control by its name and then call its `PerformClick()` method:

```
private void ShowMe(string name)
{
    var item = (MenuStripItem)this.Controls[name];
    item.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use conditional statements like if, switch

Comment: @user10976176 I edited my answer, please have a look. of course, you may need to change `this` with the parent of menustripitems

Comment: Sure brother 